# replace onmousedown with javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how can I replace onmousedown value with javascript?

for example:

```
<input style="display:inline" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="endDateAdd" id="endDate" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event,this)" onmousedown="initCal(this, '{$minCal}', null)" value="{$endDate}">
```

For the code above, I want to replace `onmousedown="initCal(this, '{$minCal}', null)" to onmousedown="initCal(this, '', null)"`. Does anyone know how to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about changing the event handler for the element when it's already on the page:

```
document.getElementById('endDate').onmousedown= function() {
    initCal(this, '', null);
};
```